# gatsby-source-wordpress error: "An empty string was returned instead of a response when making a GraphQL request."

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, gatsby

Following the steps at the [gatsby wordpress tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/wordpress-source-plugin-tutorial/), I added the necessary plugins to my wordpress and created the gatsby code. Everything is properly fetched, except for posts, I receive the following error:

> An empty string was returned instead of a response when making a GraphQL request.
> This may indicate that you have a WordPress filter running which is causing WPGraphQL
> to return an empty string instead of a response.
> Please open an issue with a reproduction at
> https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/new
> for more help
>
> Error occurred while updating a single "post" node.
>
> ERROR
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
> at fetchAndCreateSingleNode (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/update.js:76:24)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at wpActionUPDATE (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/update.js:311:20)
> at handleWpActions (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/index.js:60:7)
> at fetchAndRunWpActions (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/index.js:102:7)
> at fetchAndApplyNodeUpdates (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/fetch-node-updates.js:44:36)
> at sourceNodes (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/index.ts:60:5)
> at runSteps (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/utils/run-steps.ts:41:9)
> at runAPI (/Users/bbt/Documents/Work/my-wordpress-gatsby-site-2/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:462:16)
>
> ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_112003
>
> gatsby-source-wordpress
>
> Encountered a critical error when running the sourceNodes.sourceNodes build step.
> See above for more information.

Relevant gatsby-config.js:

```js
resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
       options: {
         url:
           process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL ||
           `https://BLOGURL.com/graphql`,
         auth: {
           htaccess: {
             username: `HTACCESS-USERNAME`,
             password: `HTACCESS-PASSWORD`,
           },
         },
         schema: {
           perPage: 5, // making it slow (suggested somewhere)
           requestConcurrency: 5, // making it slow (suggested somewhere)
           previewRequestConcurrency: 2, // making it slow (suggested somewhere)
         },
       },
```

I can query the post nodes in the wordpress graphQL without a problem, they are there.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: So you have published posts?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Yes, I have published posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way -- switched off all plugins and it worked. Switched them back one-by-one, and there was a certain plugin (something related to external links, so absolutely not something that was suspicious) that caused the problem. It works since the plugin is switched off.